# Change the title name of a XNA window?

Tags: xna

I have tried to change the title with this source:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966436.aspx

but this isn't working!? Help preciated!

Comment: You can do it with code by changing the value of `Window.Title` but both ways described in the link you posted also worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Window.Title = "My new title"`

[Riemers](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Starting_a_project.php)

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure this works, but I missed the Assembly Information button, so I changed the name that way insted!